# Why does javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader extend raw Iterator instead of Iterator<XmlEvent>?

Tags: java, stax

Why does XMLEventReader extend raw Iterator? Due to that XMLEventReader.next() returns Object and we have to use an explicit cast. Shouldn't it be this way:

```
public interface XMLEventReader extends Iterator<XmlEvent>
```

Comment: I was guessing it was added before generics, but XMLEventReader seems to have been [added in Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) (although [this page says it was added in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html)).

Comment: Hashtable is since JDK1.0, nevertheless it is generified since 1.5. Now it is Hashtable<K, V>

Comment: @BrendanLong: your first link is for the ee5 api, it was added to se in version 6, but the standard is much older.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stax api was defined in [jsr 173](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173), the specification got to final release status in march of 2004. JDK 5, which introduced generics, was only released in september 2004. The development of jsr 173 started much earlier and so it targeted an earlier java version.

It should be possible to introduce generics in a further release of the api, but I guess no one on the expert group has stepped up to the task.

Note that `XMLEventReader` also has a `nextEvent` method that does not require casting.

Comment: I notice that no one has even proposed these changes, neither on your jsr 173 link nor on http://bugs.sun.com/